# Where exactly am I to place my custom GROK regex for Logstash?

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Okay so I finally figured out how to write my regular expression for Grok using the XPack debugger. Now, my question is where exactly am I to place my custom pattern file in the system in order for Logstash to pick up the custom patterns?

And, would this be somewhat correct for the configuration to see the pattern location if folder were called 'pattern'?

```
input {
}

filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "./patterns"
        match =>["message", "%{MY_EGPATTERN:myegpattern}<%{NUMBER:number}>" ]
        break_on_match => false
    }
}

output {
}
```

PatternFile.txt saved into the ./patterns directory

```
MY_EGPATTERN [a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: The [docs suggest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-patterns_dir) to store your patterns in a subdirectory of `/opt/logstash/`, but I think your config is okay aswell. Just make sure the directory name matches exactly ('pattern' vs. "./pattern**s**")

Comment: What about the format for the pattern file that I create? I've updated the above to reflect trying to access it. I'm getting an error where it is telling me that the PATTERN IS UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 0):

Patterns dir have to be an absolute path

I usually keep mine in this folder:

```
patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns.d/"
```